# Reading XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am testing out some things with reading XML using PHP. The below is a sample of the XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<BroadcastData creationDate="20140326085217">
<ScheduleData>
<ChannelPeriod beginTime="20140326090000" endTime="20140402044500">
<ChannelId>Rai Uno</ChannelId>
<Event beginTime="20140326090000" duration="1800">
<EventId>260852180006</EventId>
<EventType>P</EventType>
<EpgProduction>
<EpgText language="eng">
<Name>Unomattina storie vere</Name>
</EpgText>
</EpgProduction>
</Event>
<Event beginTime="20140326093000" duration="1500">
<EventId>260852180007</EventId>
<EventType>P</EventType>
<EpgProduction>
<EpgText language="eng">
<Name>Unomattina Verde</Name>
</EpgText>
</EpgProduction>
</Event>
```

This is the PHP Script I built, however notthing is showing on when I run the PHP file.

```
<?php 

$completeurl ="test.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);

$info = $xml->BroadcastData->ScheduleData->ChannelPeriod->ChannelId;

for ($i = 0; $i++) {
$begintime = $info[$i]->Event->attributes()->beginTime;


echo "<p>Channel: ".$info."<br/>"."Begin Time: ".$begintime."</p>";
}



?>
```

Many thanks for your help guys !

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i > 0; $i++) {` ... do you think that loop will ever start? :)

Comment: Hi @Jack, I've amnded the for loop like this, however still it is not working: `for ($i = 0; $i++) {
    $begintime = $info[$i]->Event->attributes()->beginTime;

 
    echo "<p>Channel: ".$info."<br/>"."Begin Time: ".$begintime."</p>";
} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over each channel period rather than channel id (which is a sub element anyway):

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);

foreach ($doc->ScheduleData->ChannelPeriod as $channelPeriod) {
    $channelId = (string)$channelPeriod->ChannelId;

    foreach ($channelPeriod->Event as $event) {
        $beginTime = $event['beginTime'];

        printf('<p>Channel: %s<br />Begin Time: %s</p>', $channelId, $beginTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help @jack, I have amneded the code as follows but for some reason it is still not outputting anything: `<?php 


if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
} else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($doc->ScheduleData->ChannelPeriod as $channelPeriod) {
    $channelId = (string)$channelPeriod->ChannelId;

    foreach ($channelPeriod->Event as $event) {
        $beginTime = $event['beginTime'];

        printf('<p>Channel: %s<br />Begin Time: %s</p>', $channelId, $beginTime);
    }
}

?>`

Comment: I've tested my code on your partial XML and it works just fine.

Comment: Can you kindly provide me with the full code you used so I can replicate as it doesn't want to work, I am using mamp to test

Comment: @user3025379 I used `simplexml_load_string()`, so you just need to replace that with `simplexml_load_file()`.

Comment: ooooooo sorry didn't notice that change, I apologies. Code is working fine. Many Thanks !. Can I use the same code to post the content into a mysql database rather then output to an HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

use following function to convert the xml string into array

```
  json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($sXML)),1);
```